# Linux command to "link" files

Tags: linux

When I do "ls -lrt", there is a file that is listed and I want to create link for example,

```
myfile.config -> /users/yue/home/logs/myfile.config
```

When making changes in `myfile.config` it also affects the file in
`/users/yue/home/logs/myfile.config.`

What command in linux allows for that?
Also, what is this called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out,

Its actually "ln -s  " command

Comment: Can you close the question since you have found it. Also it is answered here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36319/symbolic-link-to-a-directory-and-relative-path

Answer (score 0):

the command is called ln  (link ) 
the basic form is  ln pathtosource pathtotarget

here is a nice URL that talks about it http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uln.htm